# Guaranteed run order of scripts

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, asynchronous, deferred

Using the following, I can get the scripts start downloading in the correct order. But I believe that because some are larger than the others file size wise, you could have one start running out of order.

```
<script defer="defer" src="http://priatek-console/bower_components/highcharts/highcharts.js"></script>

<script defer="defer" src="http://priatek-console/libs/angular.js"></script>

<script defer="defer" src="http://priatek-console/apps/home/executive.js"></script>
```

So based on the above, I assume that `executive.js` (just a few lines, dependent on angular) finishes downloading before `angular.js` (combination of angular, animate, and ui bootstrap) and I end up getting this error **AT RANDOM TIMES**:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module executiveHome due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'executiveHome' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

Therefore, my final understanding is that `defer` will begin loading the scripts in order after the page itself loads, but it won't guarantee the order they will run in since some finish downloading before others.

Is there a simple way to fix this outside of concatenating the files or using something like `require.js`? I am using John Papa's [style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide) for my `angular` code and I haven't seen anything regarding this. Nor does it recommend using `angular.bootstrap`

Comment: Why do you feel the need for `defer` in the first place? Have you tried simply placing your `script`s before the closing `body` tag, in the correct order?

Comment: Use `$q` and chain promises.

Comment: Is requirement to load scripts in order 1) highcharts.js, 2) angular.js, 3) executive.js ?

Comment: @Oka See answer #4 here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25420553/3298753

Comment: @guest271314 At the very least, `executive.js` depends on `angular.js`.

Comment: @jstudios Try loading scripts in order by checking if an object or variable within current script is defined in window before loading next script ; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26124199/run-custom-code-after-jquery-has-been-loaded-via-modernizr