# Render blocking defer vs moving script at bottom

Tags: javascript, html, performance, asynchronous, render

> I assume moving script at bottom is same as using defer or async attribute. Since defer and async are not fully legacy browser compliant, I gone with loading script at the bottom of the page.

```
<html>
<body>
<!-- whole block of html -->
<script type='text/javascript' src='app.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

> Before doing this, I ran performance benchmark tools like GTmetrix and Google PageSpeed insight. Both shown 'render blocking' parameter as the main problem. I am bit confused now, as even after I moving these scripts at the bottom to allow content/html to load first; these tools still report render blocking as a main problem.

I did look at the other StackOverflow posts highlighting that though scripts loaded at the **bottom has to have 'defer' attribute.**

I have several questions:

1. is above true?
2. are these tools specifically look for 'defer' or 'async' attribute?
3. if I have to give a fallback w.r.t defer ( specifically for IE browsers), Do I need to use conditional statements to load non-defered scripts for IE?

Kindly suggest the best approach. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not certain what question is? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: apologise if I am not able descripe it better. I am trying to optimize a HTML page which holds many of the javascripts mostly are external & application libs.

**  Since many of the performance tools suggests Javascript is causing render blocking , need to load lazy load after HTML content.

In my case , moving javascripts  to the bottom still shows render blocking as a main problem. My question is Is my understanding wrong or what do I need to do to resolve render blocking.

Comment: Have you tried loading scripts at `load` event of `window`?

Comment: Both. Initially it was in HEAD but as per suggestion, I moved it to the bottom (just before end of the body tag). Still results shown same

Comment: By loading scripts within `load` event of `window`, meaning not including `<script>` tags in `html`; but instead dynamically loading scripts within `window` `load` event handler, by dynamically creating and appending `<script>` elements to `document` after `html` has been rendered.

Comment: Not sure I understood. Did you mean inject script after the page load using document.write ?

Comment: `document.write()` is not necessary, you can use `.appendChild()`; though yes, append `<script>` element to `document` within `window` `load` event handler.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130308/discussion-between-user769456-and-guest271314).

Comment: Please *link* the answer which stated that scripts at the bottom needed a `defer` attribute

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25420553/769456

Comment: May  I conclude that , **defer & add scripts before body tag does the same thing ??**  Refer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3952081/769456) 

If its same then having scripts just before <body> tag gives me same result.

Thats why I am more confused.

Comment: Here is a very helpful article worth reading that explains how browsers work and gives tips for speeding up load times -> https://dev.to/sanjsanj/optimising-the-front-end-for-thebrowser

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Yes, the scripts loaded even at the bottom has to have defere attribute, if it's possible in your site design and requirements
2. no, those tools looks for the completion of parsing
3. depends on the version of IE that you want to support, they will have different recommendations

Now explaining simple `script`, `defer` and `async` a bit, to help you understand the reasons:

**Script**
Simple `<script>` tag will stop the parsing at that point, until the script **download** and **executes**.

**Async**
If you will use `async`, then the script will not stop parsing for download as it will continue downloading in parallel with the rest of the html content. However, the script will stop the parsing for **execution** and only then the parsing of html will continue or complete

**Defer**
If you use `defer`, the script will not halt the parsing of html data for downloading or executing the script. So it's sort of best way to avoid any time addition to the loading time of the web page.

Please note, defer is good for reducing parsing time of html, however not always best or appropriate in every webdesign flow, so be careful when you use it.

Comment: Why should the scripts mentioned at last must have defer attribute? The whole html has already been parsed and with or without defer the execution of scripts will follow the order in which they are mentioned.

Comment: parsing "ends" when </html> is parsed mate :)

Comment: I am not sure but most of pages having scripts at bottom without defer parse `</body>` and `</html>`, and hence load the page in browser, before scripts are downloaded and executed. Most probably your above comment is technically incorrect.

Comment: plz edit your last comment once you've "learnt" and become "sure" :)

Comment: If I could enlighten then why would I have set the bounty in the first place :-)

Comment: oh I didn't notice that you're the one who set the bounty :D

Comment: @user31782 even if the browser parses those nodes, it will block the onload event until the script is executed, causing many performance tools to be unhappy.

Comment: Example showing scripts before `</body>` block the onload event: https://jsfiddle.net/msotxus9/11/

Comment: It would be helpful in this answer to elaborate on when `defer` is not a good choice.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `async`, maybe something like this (thanks @guest271314 for the idea)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<!-- whole block of  html -->

<!-- inline scripts can't have async -->
<script type='text/javascript'>
function addScript(url){
document.open();
document.write("<scrip" + "t src = \"" + url + "\"></scr" + "ipt>");//weird quotes to avoid confusing the HTML parser
document.close();
}
//add your app.js last to ensure all libraries are loaded
addScript("jquery.js");
addScript("lodash.js");
addScript("app.js");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Is this what you wanted? You can add the `async` or `defer` attributes on the `document.write` call if you want.

Answer (score 0):

According to HTML Spec 1.1 The script block in the html page would block the rendering of the page till the javascript file in the url is downloaded and processed.

Adding Script at the end of the page : allow the browser to continue with the page rendering and hence the user will be able to see the page rendering asap.

**[Preferred]** Adding defer to the script tag : promises the browser that the script does not contain any document.write or document altering code in it and hence allows it to continue rendering.

As previous thread may be useful to you

[Is it necessary to put scripts at the bottom of a page when using the "defer" attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12416307/is-it-necessary-to-put-scripts-at-the-bottom-of-a-page-when-using-the-defer-at)

Answer (score 0):

Why should the scripts mentioned at last must have defer attribute?

Well, the answer is that by adding defer to last script you are actually reducing the number of critical resources that needs to be loaded before the page is painted which reduces the critical rendering path.

Yes, you are correct by the time you reach the last DOM is parsed but browser has not yet started painting the DOM and hence domContentLoadedEvent is blocked until it finishes the paint and render activity.

By adding async/defer we are telling the browser that the resource is not critical for rendering and it can be loaded and executed after dom content has loaded.
This will trigger the domContentLoaded event earlier and the sooner the domContentLoaded event fires, the sooner other application logic can begin executing.

Refer the google link below it clearly demonstrate the concept.
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/analyzing-crp